# I have a few questions about asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, xamarin

I use the following code and it works, but I'm not sure if it is the best/recommanded way to do asynchronous programming.

For example, is the following code necessary or can I call UpdateUsername() without writing this code?

```
 NewUsername();

 public async void NewUsername()
 {
   await UpdateUsername();
 }
```

I use "await" twice in my code, is it necessary to use it twice?

Is it always necessary to use "await" before some code that is marked with async, like the "await" before "PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameAsync"?

```
 private async Task UpdateUsername()
 {
   var resultupdatee = await PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameAsync(new UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameRequest()
   {
     DisplayName = "NewName"
   });

   if (resultupdatee.Error != null)
   {
     // Handle error if any
     Console.WriteLine(resultupdatee.Error.GenerateErrorReport());
   }
   else
   {
     Console.WriteLine("User display name updated");
   }
 }
```

When gets the line "int Count = 10;" executed? Is it possible that this line gets excuted before "await PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameAsync" finished?

I want that "int Count = 10;" is only then executed after the code UpdateUsername() is finished.

```
NewUsername();
int Count = 10;
```

Comment: Read the [blog from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) where he has published a lot articles about async/await - and you should read all of them (the async ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that `NewUsername` returns `void`, it does not support awaiting, so there is no need to make it an asynchronous method.

```
public void NewUsername()
{
    UpdateUsername();
}
```

But you need to ensure that `int Count = 10` executes after the asynchronous task is done, we cannot let `NewUsername` return void, otherwise there is nothing to `await`.

Based on your code I assume that there is no further operation after `UpdateUsername`, so there is no need for `NewUsername` to be a `async` method

```
public Task NewUsername()
{
    return UpdateUsername();
}
```

But if there is, you need

```
public async Task NewUsername()
{
    await UpdateUsername();
    //Operations after UpdateUsername is done.
}
```

As long as `NewUsername` returns Task, you can use `await` to ensure `int Count = 10;` executes after everything is done.

```
//Must be in an async function
await NewUsername();
int Count = 10;
```

As you can see, if there is some operation in a function A that needs to execute after another asynchronous function B is done, then function A needs to be asynchronous. In other words, asynchronous function is transitive. An asynchronous callee makes the caller asynchronous, unless you don't need to ensure the sequence of execution or you block the thread to wait synchronously.

Conclusion, there are 3 ways to do after calling an asynchronous function:

1. Waiting asynchronously, which is to `await` it to add operations after the callee is done. This makes the caller asynchronous.
2. Waiting synchronously, which is to call `Wait` method on the returned `Task` value to block the current thread for the completion. This is not recommanded for it makes the asynchronous callings meaningless.
3. Waiving the returned `Task` value of the asynchronous callee or the callee returning `void`, which is not to go ahead executing without waiting for the completion of the callee.

Comment: It's not working with public Task NewUsername(). I get an error message in this line:  await NewUsername();  Error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: As I have said, calling an async method must be within another async method.